# Laravel CSS not Instaling When Adding {id} in route

Tags: css, laravel

CSS is working when i write route

```
Route::get('/showproduct', [ShowController::class,'index'])->name('showproduct');
```

Also Controller: ShowController

```
public function index()
    {
        //
        return view('home.showproduct');
    }
```

But in that way

Route

```
Route::get('/showproduct/{id}', [ShowController::class,'index'])->name('showproduct');
```

And Controller: ShowController

```
public function index($id)
    {
        //
        return view('home.showproduct',['id'=>$id]);
    }
```

Just html is comes, css and javascript not installing.

View folder name also `showproduct.blade.php` in home folder.

Comment: I am 100% sure you are using a relative URL instead of an absolute to the CSS and JS file... if you open the Chrome or Firefox console, you will see the error...

Comment: No, i can not see any error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you include css and js is reference to relative/current directory like below:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

You should add a leading slash (`/`) to the path like below:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css">
<script src="/script.js"></script>
```

or could be better use `asset()` to use a full URL

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset('css/layouts/style-horizontal.css')}}">

<script src="{{asset('js/plugins.js')}}"></script>
```